# Remove leading spaces and the SQL> tags when spooling

Tags: sql, oracle, formatting, sqlplus, spool

I m doing an export using SQL*Plus using the following code:

```
Set echo off
Set verify off
Set feedback off
Set heading off
Set termout on
Set pages 50000 
Set linesize 1000
Set newpage none
Set colsep ","
spool Z:\ff\ss.csv
Select Client_ID, Cust_ID from cust; 
spool off;
exit;
```

I get the correct output, but it doesn't have the best formatting.

```
SQL> Select Client_ID, Cust_ID from cust; 
       100,200
       200,300
       300,400
       400,500
SQL>spool off;
```

1. How can I get rid of the spaces before the values?

   100,200
2. How can I get rid of the `SQL>` statements in the output file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`echo off` only works to remove the SQL> prompts when run from a file.  Put your commands in a file called export_client_data.sql and run them using the @ command:

```
SQL>@export_client_data.sql
```

SQL*Plus, being a reporting tool, will format output to the column width as defined in the table. Using TRIM() doesn't always work as expected because of this. You will see a VARCHAR column padded on the right to the width for example.

Typically to create an extract using SQL*Plus you would format the query like this and no need to TRIM anything:

```
Select Client_ID || ',' || Cust_ID from cust;
```

Comment: Better use `silent` option.

Answer (score 2):

Try this options :
SET TRIMSPOOL ON otherwise every line in the spoolfile is filled up with blanks until the linesize is reached.

SET TRIMOUT ON otherwise every line in the output is filled up with blanks until the linesize is reached.

SET WRAP OFF Truncates the line if its is longer then LINESIZE. This should not happen if linesize is large enough.

SET TERMOUT OFF suppresses the printing of the results to the output. The lines are still written to the spool file. This may accelerate the exectution time of a statement a lot.

Answer (score 0):

General, non-Oracle answer:

1. Use ISO/ANSI SQL function `TRIM(Client_ID)` to remove leading (and trailing) blanks. (Some DBMS's use LTRIM for leading.)
2. The non-standard REPLACE function may work, i.e. `REPLACE(Client_ID, 'SQL> ', '')`.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I get rid of the spaces before the values?

Use **TRIM**. For example,

```
SQL> SELECT TRIM(empno) eno FROM emp;

ENO
-------------------------------------
7369
7499
7521
7566
7654
7698
7782
7788
7839
7844
7876
7900
7902
7934

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```

> How can I get rid of the SQL> statements in the output file?

The best way is to use the **SILENT** option `-s`.

For example,

```
sqlplus -s scott/tiger@orcl
```

From [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch3.htm#sthref779),

> SILENT Option
>
> -S[ILENT]
>
> Suppresses all `SQL*Plus` information and prompt messages, including the command prompt, the echoing of commands, and the banner
>   normally displayed when you start `SQL*Plus`. If you omit username or
>   password, `SQL*Plus` prompts for them, but the prompts are not visible!
>   Use SILENT to invoke `SQL*Plus` within another program so that the use
>   of `SQL*Plus` is invisible to the user.
>
> SILENT is a useful mode for creating reports for the web using the SQLPLUS -MARKUP command inside a CGI script or operating system
>   script. The `SQL*Plus` banner and prompts are suppressed and do not
>   appear in reports created using the SILENT option.

Alternatively, you could also do:

```
set sqlprompt ''
```

For example,

```
SQL> set sqlprompt ''
select empno from emp;

     EMPNO
----------
      7369
      7499
      7521
      7566
      7654
      7698
      7782
      7788
      7839
      7844
      7876
      7900
      7902
      7934

14 rows selected.
```

So, the `SQL>` prompt is ignored.